# How to multiply two PyQt Qvariant values and return answer as double

Tags: qt4, pyqt4

how to multiply two PyQt Qvariant values and return them as Double. i have be trying to convert the two pyqt Qvariant values to double then multiply them i alway end up with 0.0

```
float1, ok = QVariant.toDouble (val2)`
float2, ok = QVariant.toDouble (val1)`
val3 = float2*float1 
return val3
```

`val3 alway end up 0.0
 question how do i numeric values

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without code it's hard to tell, but the [QVariant docs](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qvariant.html#toDouble) state

> (float, bool ok) QVariant.toDouble (self)
>
> Returns the variant as a float if the variant has type() Double, QMetaType.Float, Bool, ByteArray, Int, LongLong, String, UInt, or ULongLong; otherwise returns 0.0.

Are you sure that your QVariants are one of those types?

**EDIT**

From your code I see you are calling `QVariant.toDouble()`.  Try calling `.toDouble()` on your QVariant instances.  For example, this code works for me.

```
>>> val1=QtCore.QVariant(12.0)
>>> val2=QtCore.QVariant(11.0)
>>> float1, ok = val1.toDouble()
>>> float2, ok = val2.toDouble()
>>> val3=float2*float1
>>> print val3
132.0
```

Comment: thank for the answer it returns float but when i try multiply it with another returned float i get 0.0